# How do I remove H1 tags from the_content and insert in my header file in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the H1 tags (and their enclosing content) from this part of the content-page.php file in my WordPress site:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

And I want to insert those same H1 tags at a specific location in my header.php file. Is there a programmatic way to do this?

Comment: easy is an opinion, what have you tried?

Comment: So far, all I did was try putting <?php the_content(); ?> in my header.php file to get the content in there, but that didn't seem to work. I thought I could strip out the rest of the stuff, but maybe the_content isn't available yet (in the header.php file)? I felt I was going about this the wrong way, so that's why I'm asking. I will take out the word "easy" from my question. :)

Comment: $content = get_the_content(); will assign the string value to that variable. You can then parse it out with some work. The real question is why you would put the h1 in the body at all? Why not just use a plugin like custom fields and make a separate h1 field?

Comment: I'm thinking that is what I should do. Use a plugin or create a widget instead.